# Switch Case in dwoo syntax

Tags: switch-statement, dwoo

How do you do a switch case syntax using Dwoo template engine.

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how many new things I learn about just by browsing SO. It also never ceases to amaze me how wrong it is to leave the responsibility of product naming in the hands of geeks :-) Seriously, "dwoo"? I think I wiped some of that off the bottom of my shoes last week.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You might be better off using a regular function, passing your variable as parameter in and render partial templates inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
{if 3 == 5}
  never gonna happen
{elseif 3 == 3}
  if you don't see this, the world is coming to its end
{else}
  this will never happen, unless, as previously mentionned, the world is coming to its end
{/if}
```

http://wiki.dwoo.org/index.php/If